# QCustomPlot display time in HH:MM:SS

Tags: c++, qt, timeline, qcustomplot

I was wondering either it is possible in the QCustomPlot library to change display format of the data on one of the axis. In my application on the X axis I have time in seconds and I would like to display the steps in HH:MM:SS instead. As an alternative I am thinking of changing the display only from seconds to minutes to hours depending on the X lenght and updating the label from Time [s] to [min] to [hour]. But I would avoid that if its possible to do it the way I described. I Would appreciate all help!

When using:

```
customPlot->xAxis->setTickLabelType(QCPAxis::ltDateTime);
customPlot->xAxis->setDateTimeFormat("hh:mm:ss");
```

My timeline starts from hour 1 instead of 0:
[image]
Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: It's your timezone settings. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31093640/setdatetimeformat-adds-an-hour/31093786#31093786

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`setTickLabelType()`](http://www.qcustomplot.com/documentation/classQCPAxis.html#a54f24f5ce8feea25209388a863d7e448) and [`setDateTimeFormat`](http://www.qcustomplot.com/documentation/classQCPAxis.html#a2ee0191daa03524a682113e63e05f7a7):

```
plot->xAxis->setTickLabelType(QCPAxis::ltDateTime);
plot->xAxis->setDateTimeFormat("hh:mm:ss");
```

The format string is built according to the the format string of  [`QDateTime::toString()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#toString).

Answer (score 0):

```
// Создаем формат отображения дискретных отсчетов времени захвата мгновенного курса судна
QSharedPointer<QCPAxisTickerDateTime> dateTicker(new QCPAxisTickerDateTime);
// Установка формата отображения времени захвата мгновенного курса судна
dateTicker->setDateTimeFormat("hh:mm:ss");
// Передаем вектор подписей в график
m_QCustomPlot->yAxis->setTicker(dateTicker);
```