# setDateTimeFormat adds an hour

Tags: c++, qt, date, time, qcustomplot

I would like to display my x axis in the hh:mm:ss format. It basicaly works, but there is one problem. The displayed time doesnt start from 00:00:00 but from 01:00:00. I thought maybe its because the time is in ap mode, but I havent specified that, here is how I do it:

```
customPlot->xAxis->setTickLabelType(QCPAxis::ltDateTime);
customPlot->xAxis->setDateTimeFormat("hh:mm:ss");
```

And the plot at point 0 starts from hour 1:

[image]

I would appreciate all help regarding this. How to make the starting point 0 shown as 00:00:00?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `HH` (or `H` to avoid the leading zero). Lowercase `h` is for AM/PM hour format, which starts to count from 1.

Font: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#toString

If the problem still persists, it should be timezone related. Add

`customPlot->xAxis->setDateTimeSpec(Qt::UTC)`

before `SetTimeFormat`

Comment: So it should be timezone settings (if you are GMT +1). Edited the answer.

Comment: Is there a way to make this time zone independent?